# Which method to use to test the effect of a dichotomous independent variable on a continuous dependent variable?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mean, random-variable

My apologies in advance if there are fundamental mistakes or wrong assumptions in my question. Also I am making up the example so there may be inconsistencies.

I’ll explain this with an example. I have a dataset containing information on employed individuals in a city. For my purpose, the dependent variable is the annual income which is a continuous random variable with a mean of 45000. There are 5 discrete independent variables (gender, college graduate, # of people in household, criminal record and zipcode).

I want to check the effect of the variable college graduate on the dependent variable (annual income). When I subgroup the data into two groups (college graduates vs non-college graduates), one has a mean of ~51000 while the other group has a mean of ~34000.

My questions then are:

1. what is a sound method to check if the difference in the means of the two subgroups is significant & caused by the selected independent variable.
2. How can I quantify the value of a college degree (ie. $17,000 annually which is the difference of means of the two subgroups)

My knowledge suggests regression. However my problems with that are that I don’t know if the relationship is linear and if I should include all the independent variables in the regression model or just the one I’m examining

Thanks!